# Else statement acting like it doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm new to python and im writing this quick project, but whenever I add an elif statement to my 
code it completely ignores the else statement and prints the elif statement that breaks the loop does anyone know why?

```
user_input7 = input("What is my favorite game?")
while True:
    if user_input7 =="Hint" or user_input7 == "hint":
        print("The first two letters of the first word start with ho.")
        user_input7 = input("What's my favorite game?")
        continue
    elif user_input7 == "idk" or user_input7 == "i dont know":
        print("uh if you don't know it type hint")
        user_input7 = input("What's my favorite game?")
        continue
    elif user_input7 == "Hollow Knight" or "hollow knight" or "Hollow knight":
        print("About time you got that one")
        break
    else:
        print("Why isn't this working")
```

Comment: Missing `user_input7 ==` as part of the check to the last two `or`'s in the last `elif` condition.

Comment: the last `elif` will always be `True` for the items that are missing `user_input7 == ...`